# Trying to fill input field when user clicks away outside of input in jquery

Tags: function, jquery

I am quite new to jquery so sorry if this is basic.

I currently has a function that empties the value of a username input field so the user doesn't have to  delete it before entering their username.

```
   $("#usernameInput").click(function(){
        $(this).val("");
    });
```

But I am stuck trying to refill the input field with "username" if the user hasn't entered anything in the input field once they when the click outside of the input field after having clicked in it and clearing it with the previous function.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$("html").click(function(){
    if( $("usernameInput").val() == " " ){
        $("usernameInput").val("username");
    }
    else{
        //do nothing as user has entered username
    }


});
```

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from adding a `placeholder="Username"` attribute to the input tag.

Comment: Thanks Matt, nice to see html5 has simplified this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd normally use the focus and blur events for that

```
$("#usernameInput").on({
    focus: function(){
        if (this.value.trim() == 'username') this.value = '';
    },
    blur: function() {
        if (!this.value.trim().length) this.value = 'username';
    }
});
```

or in HTML5 you can use a placeholder

```
<input type="text" id="usernameInput" placeholder="username" />
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wUUzD/)

Comment: Thanks, you were quick! I assume in the blur function I can use an if statement to only change the value to username if nothing has been entered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#usernameInput").focusout(function(){
    if(this.value == ""){
        $("usernameInput").val("username");
    }
    else{
        //do nothing as user has entered username
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#usernameInput").focus(function(){
    $(this).val("");
});

$("#usernameInput").blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length < 1)
    {
      $(this).val("username");
    }
});
```